# How to prevent current location from jumping around the map

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app I have a map, which displays current location. Im using google_maps_flutter plugin, and enabled current location. The problem is, that when Im standing still, the location still moves around.

Can this somehow be prevented? To just completely freeze the map when standing still?

Comment: That's because of less accuracy of your location in meters, even Google Maps does that sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong at your end, it is just how Google Maps work if it has less accuracy of the current location, it keeps jumping until it finds bit more accuracy.

You may want to test your app outdoor where GPS has better reception of satellites due to clear view of sky.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use[Location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package to get current location instead of google map's, you can control the time interval of retrieving current location